# Linear Interpolation and the linear correlation coefficient: $r^2$

Tags: statistics

Below is a problem I did. I believe I did it correctly and I was able to confirm the answer with R. The script is included
at the end of the post. My intution says that $r^2$ should be smaller. Is my intution wrong? Is my solution wrong?

Problem:

Fit a least-square line to the data given below with $x$ as the independent variable and $y$ as the dependent variable. Then find
$r^2$.
Here is the list of x values: $3,5,6,8,9,11$.

Here is the list of y values: $2,3,4,6,5,8$.
Answer:

We want to find an equation of the form:
$$ y = bx + a $$
To do this, we set up the following system of two equations.
\begin{align*}
\sum y &= an + b \sum x \\
\sum xy &= a \sum x + b \sum x^2
\end{align*}
We now find the things we can find and come up with two equations.
\begin{align*}
\sum y &= 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 5 + 8 = 15 + 5 + 8 \\
\sum y &= 28 \\
\sum x &= 3 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 + 11 = 22 + 9 + 11 \\
\sum x &= 42 \\
\sum xy &= 3(2) + 5(3) + 6(4) + 8(6) + 9(5) + 11(8) \\
\sum xy &= 21 + 6(4) + 8(6) + 9(5) + 11(8) = 21 + 24 + 48 + 45 + 11(8) \\
\sum xy &= 226 \\
\sum x^2 &= 3^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 11^2 = 34 + 36 + 64 + 81 + 121 \\
\sum x^2 &= 336 \\
n &= 6 \\
\end{align*}
Now we have our two equations:
\begin{align*}
6a + 42b &= 28\\
42a + 336b &= 226 \\
6a &= 28 - 42b \\
3a &= 14 - 21b \\
a &= \frac{14 - 21b}{3} \\
42 \left( \frac{14 - 21b}{3} \right) + 336b &= 226 \\
14( 14 - 21b )  + 336b &= 226 \\
196 - 294b + 336b = 226 \\
-294b +336b &= 30 \\
-147b + 168b &= 15 \\
21b &= 15 \\
7b &= 5 \\
b &= \frac{5}{7} \\
a &= \frac{14 - 21\left( \frac{5}{7} \right) }{3} \\
a &= \frac{14 - 3(5)}{3} \\
a &= -\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y = \left( \frac{5}{7} \right) x  -\frac{1}{3} $$
Now we need to find $r^2$.
$$ r^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum ( y - y_{est})^2}{\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 } $$
We compute $y_{est}$ from $x$, using the equation we found that relates $x$ and $y$. Here are the values
for $y_{est}$.
$$ y_{est} = \frac{38}{21}, \frac{68}{21}, \frac{83}{21}, \frac{113}{21}, \frac{128}{21}, \frac{158}{21}   $$
\begin{align*}
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \left(  2 - \frac{38}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( 3 - \frac{68}{21} \right) ^ 2 \\
&+ \left( 4 - \frac{83}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( 6 - \frac{113}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( 5 - \frac{128}{21} \right) ^ 2 +
\left( 8 - \frac{158}{21} \right) ^ 2 \\
%
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \left( \frac{42 - 38}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{63 - 68}{21} \right) ^ 2 \\
&+ \left( \frac{84 - 83}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{126 - 113}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{105 - 128}{21} \right) ^ 2 +
\left( \frac{168 - 158}{21} \right) ^ 2 \\
%
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \left( \frac{4}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{-5}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{1}{21} \right) ^ 2
+ \left( \frac{-13}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{-23}{21} \right) ^ 2
+ \left( \frac{10}{21} \right) ^ 2 \\
%
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \frac{16}{441}+ \left( \frac{-5}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{1}{21} \right) ^ 2
+ \left( \frac{-13}{21} \right) ^ 2 + \left( \frac{-23}{21} \right) ^ 2
+ \left( \frac{10}{21} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \frac{16}{441} + \frac{25}{441} + \frac{1}{441}
+ \frac{169}{441} + \frac{529}{441} +  \frac{100}{441} \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \frac{16+25+1+169+529+100}{441} \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \frac{840}{441} = \frac{280}{147}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\overline{y} &= \frac{ \sum y }{n } = \frac{28}{6} \\
\overline{y} &= \frac{14}{3} \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 &= \left( 2 -  \frac{14}{3}  \right)^2 + \left( 3 -  \frac{14}{3}  \right)^2 +
\left( 4 -  \frac{14}{3} \right)^2 + \left( 6 -  \frac{14}{3}  \right)^2  \\
&+ \left( 5 -  \frac{14}{3}  \right)^2
+ \left( 8 -  \frac{14}{3} \right)^2 \\
%
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 &= \left( \frac{6 - 14}{3}  \right)^2 + \left( \frac{9 - 14}{3}  \right)^2 +
\left( \frac{16 - 14}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{18 - 14}{3}  \right)^2  \\
&+ \left( \frac{15 -  14}{3}  \right)^2
+ \left( \frac{24 - 14}{3} \right)^2 \\
%
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 &= \left( \frac{-8}{3}  \right)^2 + \left( \frac{-5}{3}  \right)^2 +
\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{4}{3}  \right)^2 \\
&+ \left( \frac{1}{3}  \right)^2 + \left( \frac{10}{3} \right)^2 \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 &= \frac{ 64 + 25 + 4 + 16 + 1 + 100 }{9} = \frac{210}{9} \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 &= \frac{70}{3}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
r^2 &= 1 - \frac{ \frac{280}{147} }{ \frac{70}{3}} = 1 - \frac{280(3)}{147(70)} = \frac{3(28)}{7(147)} \\
r^2 &= 1 - \frac{28}{7(49)} = \frac{7(49) - 28}{7(49)} \\
r^2 &= \frac{315}{343} \\
r^2 &\doteq 0.9183673
\end{align*}
This value for $r^2$ was checked with the following R script:
x = c(  3 , 5 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 11 )
y = c (2 , 3 , 4 , 6 , 5 , 8 )
lm( y ~ x )
s = lm( y ~ x )
summary(s)

Comment: Maybe more appropriate on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GabrielRomon I have posted there but they do not handle calculations. That is, they do not handle the math behind the statistics and they will not find errors in math. They handle statistics from a high level. Therefore, I feel that my post here does not belong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You checked your calculations with R and they confirmed $r^2 \approx 0.9184$ so it is unlikely you made an error.

Another check with simple linear regression is to say the correlation $r_{x,y}=b \frac{s_x}{s_y}$, which here is about $0.9583$ and its square is about $0.9184$

Finally you could plot the data and regression line with

```
plot(y ~ x)
abline(s)
```

and see that the line is a pretty good fit

[image]